# IS there any alternate combination of image and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one text and one image and both are clickable. So I am using anchor and image tag.

Here is a code.

```
myData.text = "<a style='color:#0000ff' onClick='func(event," + JSON.stringify(myData) + ")' href='javascript:void(0);'>"+Countary Data Connection +"</a>"+"<img src='Images/image.png' style='padding-left:2px' onClick='someFunc(event," + JSON.stringify(myData) + ")'></img>";
```

Here is my image.

[image]

Fiddler[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal/v2uhzL0k/)
All click event and all everything is fine. I have a two question here.

1. Is there any other way or tag which I can use or this is the only way ? (anchor+img)
2. My image is not alling to text. How to make it alling. (If I give `padding-top` then whole (text+image) both are coming down.). How to fix that.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I updated question. You can see text and image are not align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `a` and `img` into a `span` and attach function to parent element (`span`), and for alignment, add `vertical-align: middle;` to `img`, bydefault inline elements are aligned to baseline that's why adding padding was moving both elements to the bottom.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span onClick='func(event," + JSON.stringify(myData) + ")'><a style='color:#0000ff' href='javascript:void(0);'>Countary Data Connection </a>
<img src='Images/image.png'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put image inside the "A" tag and bind function on "A" tag and yes off course image needs to be vertically in middle so it will works parallel of text.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='func(event," + JSON.stringify(myData) + ")' >Hello World <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands/512/twitter-24.png" /></a>

img {
vertical-align : middle
}
```

[Live demo here](https://codepen.io/uicreation/pen/MrpdjY)